# How to add google map pathways in Android application?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have start and end rout latitude and longitudes.

Along with this I have some other points which are in between the start and end point. So I want to create a path/route/pathway which shows all the points from start to end.

I tried google but receive no such results which could help.

like for two points, code is like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345");
startActivity(intent);
```

but I want the one for complete route which cover multiple points. like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a MapView for that.

And in order to retrieve the path between your two points, just get the content of `http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=47.295601,0.010586&daddr=47.295601,1.010586&output=kml` (notice the "&output=kml") and parse it. In this file, you can get the complete path in the "GeometryCollection" element.

If the file is empty, no route has been found.

Comment: thanks, but I have some other points in between and I want that map must also touch that points too while completing the path. I wrote the code for two points but I want to include that points too

Comment: You need to modify the "daddr" field of the url by adding "+to:" in front of each checkpoint. For example : `http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=47.295601,0.010586&daddr=47.295601,1.010586+to:47.295601,2.010586+to:47.295601,3.010586`

Comment: you mean code should look like this                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=47.295601,0.010586&daddr=47.295601,1.010586+t‌​o:47.295601,2.010586+to:47.295601,3.010586");
startActivity(intent);

Comment: How if I use addresses instead of latitude/Longitude, then what should be the format

Comment: The format is the same, just replace coordinates by addresses. Ex : `http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Paris,+France&daddr=Marseille,+France+to:Bordeaux,+France+to:Rennes,+France`. Use "+" instead of spaces and it should be fine. However, I think it could be a problem if there is some ambiguity with the address you provide so you have to be really specific if you use that method.